# Web app for PhoneGap, should I develop separately first?

Tags: cordova

So I am planning on developing an app using PhoneGap.

I will also be learning jQuery as I go so just wondering is it possible to develop the guts of the app outside the PhoneGap environment i.e. Notepad + Browser?

Most of the app just consists of UI and Ajax calls to an API. I am thinking it would be easier to develop and debug outside DG.

I am worried that I will need to patch loads of my code to get it working in PG, or is it just a case of dropping it in with minimal changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should build as much of the application in the web browser first before you wrap it up in a native app using PhoneGap. Certainly it is easier to debug the HTML using Chrome/Safari web developer tools. When you eventually do wrap it into a native application you can use [Weinre](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/) to debug your app remotely.

Also, check out the [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html) docs on how to setup your AJAX connection to work around the CORS restrictions.